# Помогите определить, к чему относится причастный оборот

Tags: причастный-оборот

Предложение следующее:

> В соответствии с условиями сбор вещей осуществляется в пакеты или иные
>   ёмкости, предоставленные организатором.

Относится ли причастие "предоставленные" к слову "пакеты"? или только к слову "ёмкости"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Формально "предоставленные" может относиться к "пакеты или иные ёмкости" или только к "иные ёмкости". Но по смыслу ясно, что имеет место первый случай. (Если бы только иные ёмкости были предоставлены организатором, то было бы указано, кем предоставлены пакеты.)

Comment: Благодарю за Ваше мнение. Хотел бы уточнить: а если по отношению к пакетам не имеет значение кем они предоставлены? Например, пакет может быть любым, а иная ёмкость может именно той, что предоставил организатор.

Comment: Формально возможно такое понимание: пакеты (любые) или иные ёмкости, предоставленные организатором. Но грамотно составленный текст не должет оставлять недоговоренностей, то есть то, что пакеты – любые, нужно указать явно (в любые пакеты или в ёмкости, предоставленные организатором). Как минимум, следовало бы повторить предлог *в*. То, что предлог общий, заставляет думать, что и оборот общий.

Comment: Благодарю за развеянные сомнения